# Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

How to Add data from a webserver (I've to parse the xml response using Dom) and display the content in a listview. And also i want an id for each of the list elements. So i can implement onclick methods also.  Please help me onto this...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you don't know much about Android's ListView. Read through this, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html, it's a tutorial for a simple list view, it'll teach you to add data and how to handle item selections.